# How to call an asynchronous JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Can anyone please help me with the following, I am new to Async\Await in Javascript:

I have a trivial class:

```
function Thing()
{
}

Thing.prototype.ShowResult = function ()
{
    var result = this.GetAsync();

    alert(result);
}

Thing.prototype.GetAsync = async function ()
{
    var result = await this.AsyncFunc();

    return result;
}

Thing.prototype.AsyncFunc = async function ()
{
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(6);
        }, 2000);
    });
}
```

I call it like this:

```
var thing = new Thing();

thing.ShowResult();
```

I expected a delay of 2 seconds before seeing the result of 6.

Instead I immediately see:

[object Promise]

How can I correctly await the result? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Notice you realize it's necessary to `await` in `GetAsync()`. Why do you think it's not necessary in `ShowResult()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though AsyncFunc and GetAsync are async functions. ShowResult function is not. It is necessary for the parent function to be async as well. The below code returns 6.

```
function Thing()
{
}

Thing.prototype.ShowResult = async function ()
{
    var result = await this.GetAsync();

    alert(result);
}

Thing.prototype.GetAsync = async function ()
{
    var result = await this.AsyncFunc();

    return result;
}

Thing.prototype.AsyncFunc = async function ()
{
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(6);
        }, 2000);
    });
}

var thing = new Thing();

thing.ShowResult();
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to make the parent `function` consuming the `async` `function` `async` as well.

```js
function Thing() {}

Thing.prototype.ShowResult = async function() { // add async
  var result = await this.GetAsync(); // await the response

  alert(result);
}

Thing.prototype.GetAsync = async function() {
  var result = await this.AsyncFunc();

  return result;
}

Thing.prototype.AsyncFunc = async function() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(6);
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

Then you can call `ShowResult`

```
var thing = new Thing();

await thing.ShowResult();
```

But, if you're calling `thing.ShowResult` outside of an `async` `function` you'll have to use the `Promise` syntax since you can't `await` something that isn't in an `async` `function`. There's no concept of a "top level await" in JS. Yet.

```
var thing = new Thing();

thing.ShowResult().then( result => console.log(result) );
```

Comment: [Stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) with
[implementor support](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await), it's just a matter of time before it's officially in the specification.

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't realize that it had made it that far in the pipeline. I know some popular frameworks that have the concept but didn't think it'd make it to JS for awhile. This is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, async functions always return a Promise (this is why you see `[object Promise]`), which can be resolved either by calling its `then` method or by using the `await` keyword. For now, `await` can only be used inside async functions.

To apply this to your problem, you can do one of the following:

**#1**

```js
Thing.prototype.ShowResult = function ()
{
    this.GetAsync().then(alert);
}

thing.ShowResult();
```

**#2**

In this approach, `ShowResult` is also an async function. So what I wrote above also applies to it.

```js
Thing.prototype.ShowResult = async function ()
{
    var result = await this.GetAsync();
}

await thing.ShowResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function GetAsync() return a promise to consume the promise you have to either use `await` or `.then` read more about [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```js
function Thing() {}

Thing.prototype.ShowResult = async function() {
  var result = await this.GetAsync();
  alert(result);
}

Thing.prototype.GetAsync = async function() {
  var result = await this.AsyncFunc();
  return result;
}

Thing.prototype.AsyncFunc = async function() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(6);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

var thing = new Thing();

thing.ShowResult();
```

using `.then`

```js
function Thing() {}

Thing.prototype.ShowResult = async function() {
  var result =  this.GetAsync().then((result)=>alert(result));
}

Thing.prototype.GetAsync = async function() {
  var result = await this.AsyncFunc();
  return result;
}

Thing.prototype.AsyncFunc = async function() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(6);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

var thing = new Thing();

thing.ShowResult();
```